# Why is the bed texture reversed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've recently updated to Minecraft 1.7.2 and I've found out that the bed texture is somehow reversed on the side. I've searched here for a similar question but couldn't find one. Is it just me or is it a problem of the current snapshot? How can I fix it?

[image: An image showing a bed placed down with its left side textures flipped]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Reversed textures is a bug in 1.7.2 that affects multiple North and East side textures.](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-37106) It's just way more obvious on beds than on most other blocks.

It's already marked as fixed in the bugtracker (so, fixed in Mojang's in-development code), so the fix will probably appear in the next update.

Comment: For the record, my bed texture's is broken on all 4 sides (north, east, south, west).